# Why isn't the determinant function zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ be $n$ dimensional column vectors. The determinant function $D(P_1,\ldots,P_n)$ is a multilinear, alternating real function of these vectors. Since it's alternating, if $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ are not linearly independent, then $D$ evaluates to zero. So far so good. Let $E_1,\ldots,E_n$ be the standard basis column vectors ($n$-dimensional). Let the $i$-th entry in $P_j$ be $p^i_j$.

My question is: due to multilinearity can't I write $D(P_1,\ldots,P_n)$ as

$$D(p^1_1E_1,\ldots,p^1_nE_1)+D(p^2_1E_2,\ldots,p^2_nE_2)+\ldots+D(p^n_1E_n,\ldots,p^n_nE_n)$$ and say that all terms are zero, since in each term, the arguments are not independent? So the entire thing must be zero? I'm not able to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: It looks like you're saying something like $D(A, B) + D(E, F) = D(A + E, B + F)$. Multilinearity is **not** that.

Comment: So one can only resolve it one argument at a time? Can I do it step by step and say that $D(A+E,B+F)=D(A,B+F)+D(E,B+F)=(D(A,B)+D(A,F))+(D(E,B)+D(E,F))$? Is that the correct definition?

Comment: Yes, but if you do that, you will find that one of your terms is precisely $D(P_1,\ldots,P_n)$, so you end up with an equation that says that $D(P_1,\ldots,P_n)$ is equal to itself plus a bunch of terms that evaluate to $0$.

Comment: @user9343456: Yes, that is correct. So you'd end up with some $n^n$ terms, out of which only $n!$ many would possibly be non-zero. But in any case, you wouldn't get anything very interesting out of it.

Comment: Also the thing is not quite right, since $p_j^iE_i$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, not a column.